# Not set css attributes to child elements. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `div` with a `table` inside. Inside the `td` elements of the table, I have text and some links that have 'actionLink' class assign.

Using JQuery, I change some attribute values to the `td` and `p` elements inside the parent `div`. All works fine, but that the attribute values for a links also change.

Is there a way to change this attributes without affecting the `a` elements.

This is what I have

JavaScript

```
    $('.sectionContent').css("color", $('#ParagraphForegroundColor').val());
    $('.sectionContent').css("background-color", $('#ParagraphBackgroundColor').val());
    $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-family", $('#ParagraphFontFamily').val());
    $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-size", $('#ParagraphFontSize').val());
    $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-style", $('#ParagraphFontStyle').val());
    $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-weight", $('#ParagraphFontWeight').val());
    $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("text-decoration", $('#ParagraphTextDecoration').val());
```

Comment: Where you selecting `a` tags? can you post all your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can see the html as well?

Comment: the `a` taqgs are located inside some `td`s. The page is dynamically generated. I'll try to extract some part of it

Comment: You talk about an "actionLink" class, but it's not anywhere in your jQuery selectors.

Comment: the `actionLink` class is applied to some `a` tags inside the `.sectionContent td`s. When I update the css attributes to `.sectionContent td`s, `actionLink` element attributes are overwritten. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Setting CSS properties won't overwrite any class. It will (as I point out in my updated answer) have an effect on the sttings inherited by descendants of the elements you update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you simply need to define the class actionLink in css so that it doesn't inherit the properties of the TD that's containing it.

Something like

```
.actionLink{
 font-family:vlaue;
 font-size:vlaue;
 font-weight:vlaue;
 font-style:vlaue;
 text-decoration:vlaue;
}
```

**EDIT :**

For Instance, this works fine:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
             $('.sectionContent').css("color", 'blue');
            $('.sectionContent').css("background-color", 'red');
            $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-family", '"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif');
            $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-size", '11pt');
            $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-style", 'normal');
            $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("font-weight", 'normal');
            $('.sectionContent p, .sectionContent td').not(".addColumn").css("text-decoration", 'none');
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .actionLink{
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:6pt;
             font-weight:bold;
             font-style:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
             background-color:white;
             color:black;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sectionContent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Some Test
                    <a class='actionLink'>Action</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right on the spot. I was setting some other attributes to that class, but not the ones I was changing with JavsScript

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Looking more closely at your selectors, the selectors you've shown don't match **any** `a` elements at all unless they have the class "sectionContent", in which case they're matched by your first two lines that apply to *all* elements with the "sectionContent" class. But the remaining five lines clearly select *only* `p` and `td` elements, and so won't have any (direct) effect on `a` elements at all.

They could have an indirect effect, of course. If the `a` elements are inheriting their font settings from the `p` or `td` they're in (and they frequently do), then of course changing the font settings on the `p` or `td` will affect the `a` indirectly because it's inheriting them. No way 'round that other than to explicitly set font settings on the `a` elements so they don't inherit anymore.

For example:

CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: serif;
}
a.actionLink {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>This is the paragraph with <a href="#" class="actionLink">an 'actionLink' link in it</a>.
```

JavaScript:

```
$("p").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Now the link is in bold, because it was inheriting its `font-weight` from its parent element. In contrast:

```
$("p").css("font-family", "Comic Sans"); // Hey, I had to do it
```

That has no effect on the `a` element, because it has its *own* `font-family` setting.

---

**Original answer**:

Hard to answer specifically without seeing your markup, but generally: You can set your selectors to only match elements that have the class ***and*** have a certain tag name, e.g.:

```
// Matches *all* elements with the class "className"
$(".className")

// Only matches `p` elements with "className"
$("p.className")

// Only matches `td` and `p` elements with "className"
$("p.className, td.className")
```

jQuery supports nearly the full range of CSS3 selectors, and then some. Details:

- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
- [CSS2.1 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) (but the CSS3 stuff supercedes this)